# Error polyline google maps

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

```
$.getJSON('/polyline/', function(data) { 
        $.each( data.markers, function(i, line) {
              var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: line.title,
              });

                var line_lat_lon = new google.maps.LatLng(line.latitude, line.longitude);
                var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: line_lat_lon,
                    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    map: map_canvas,
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(line, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map_canvas,line);
            });             
        });
      });
```

Hi, i need to draw a line in my map, so i used the Google Maps function *Polyline*.
I'm getting an error because google.maps.Polyline needs an array of LatLng to create the line.
Can someone help me to turn *line_lat_lon* into an array to solve this?
Thanks.

Sample JSON (from comment):

```
{"markers": [{"latitude": "-27.48699568", "longitude": "-48.732537\r"},
{"latitude": "-27.48777704", "longitude": "-48.73220148\r"}, 
{"latitude": "-27.48987386", "longitude": "-48.73255083\r"}, 
{"latitude": "-27.49196204", "longitude": "-48.73290095\r"}, 
{"latitude": "-27.49375971", "longitude": "-48.73111728\r"}, 
{"latitude": "-27.49701558", "longitude" ... (cutoff)
```

Comment: What does your JSON look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue (need your JSON to do that).

Comment: {"markers": [{"latitude": "-27.48699568", "longitude": "-48.732537\r"}, {"latitude": "-27.48777704", "longitude": "-48.73220148\r"}, {"latitude": "-27.48987386", "longitude": "-48.73255083\r"}, {"latitude": "-27.49196204", "longitude": "-48.73290095\r"}, {"latitude": "-27.49375971", "longitude": "-48.73111728\r"}, {"latitude": "-27.49701558", "longitude" That's my JSON

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, edit your question to include any requested information.  I have edited your question to include the (partial) JSON you provided, please edit your question to include a complete sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the polyline an array of google.maps.LatLng objects:

```
$.getJSON('/polyline/', function(data) { 
    var line_lat_lon = [];
    $.each( data.markers, function(i, line) {
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: line.title,
          });

          line_lat_lon.push(new google.maps.LatLng(line.latitude, line.longitude));


          google.maps.event.addListener(line, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map_canvas,line);
          });             
    });
    var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: line_lat_lon,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                map: map_canvas,
        });
});
```

Comment: If this worked for you and answers your question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)